# Noob Rails 3 link_to question

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, link-to

Lets say we have a `Article` with many `Comments`.

`Comments` are added into the article in a separate "create comment for article XYZ" - page.

I'd like to have a "add comment" link on every article page.

But in the comments controller, I need to have information about the parent article the comment is added to.

So how do I pass along the article information (`article_id`) through the `link_to` to the comments create page?

Comment: Can you title your question more descriptively?

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= link_to "add comment", new_comment_path(:article_id => article_id) %>
```

Then in your Comments controller, the "new" action:

```
@article_id = params[:article_id]
```

Then in the Views/Comments/new.html.erb you have access to the @article_id variable and are able to insert into the form with a hidden field and pass it to the create action...